# each two columns in the excel file are separated into multiple csv files

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have this excel file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/14a37hTH2fv48QdCLlY-5G-3Jzku9MxmZ/view?usp=drivesdk
I want to put each two consecutive columns in a separate .csv file
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(df.shape[1]/2):
    df[df.columns[2*i:2*i+2]].to_csv(f'data_{i+1}.csv')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After you loaded your excel file you can loop by twos

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(0, number_of_columns, 2):
  np.savetxt(str(i) + '.csv', your_data, fmt='%s', delimiter=';')  # saving each 2 consecutive columns as 1.csv to e.g. 20.csv
```

If you have a DataFrame and you want to use this solution use `your_data.to_numpy()`